# Struggling with a Object value

Tags: php, arrays

my registrar is changing API and I am trying to automate my DDNS file.

Via the API I can authorize and get all my domain data:

```
Array
(
[0] => Transip\Api\Library\Entity\Domain Object
    (
        [name:protected] => myfirstdomain.org
        [authCode:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
        [isTransferLocked:protected] => 
        [registrationDate:protected] => 2020-01-17
        [renewalDate:protected] => 2022-01-17
        [isWhitelabel:protected] => 
        [cancellationDate:protected] => 
        [cancellationStatus:protected] => 
        [isDnsOnly:protected] => 
        [hasAutoDns:protected] => 
        [tags:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Transip\Api\Library\Entity\Domain Object
    (
        [name:protected] => myseconddomain.org
        [authCode:protected] => xxxxxxxxxx
        [isTransferLocked:protected] => 
        [registrationDate:protected] => 2009-03-22
        [renewalDate:protected] => 2022-03-22
        [isWhitelabel:protected] => 
        [cancellationDate:protected] => 
        [cancellationStatus:protected] => 
        [isDnsOnly:protected] => 
        [hasAutoDns:protected] => 
        [tags:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[2] => Transip\Api\Library\Entity\Domain Object
    (
        [name:protected] => mythirddomain.org
        [authCode:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        [isTransferLocked:protected] => 
        [registrationDate:protected] => 2011-09-17
        [renewalDate:protected] => 2022-09-17
        [isWhitelabel:protected] => 
        [cancellationDate:protected] => 
        [cancellationStatus:protected] => 
        [isDnsOnly:protected] => 
        [hasAutoDns:protected] => 
        [tags:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

Now I want to just extract the domain names to use in a update script. Unfortunatly I can't seem to manage it:

```
//get all domain information
$domains = $api->domains()->getAll();
//this pulls all the first domain data
$firstDomain = $domains[0];
//Trying to strip the [name] value
$firstDomainName = $firstDomain->name;
```

The last line unfortunately kicks a error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property Transip\Api\Library\Entity\Domain::$name in /myserver/websitefolder/Check.php:22
```

If I json_encode $domains:

```
[{"name":"myfirstdomain.org","authCode":"xxxxxxxxxx","isTransferLocked":false,"registrationDate":"2020-01-17","renewalDate":"2022-01-17","isWhitelabel":false,"cancellationDate":"","cancellationStatus":"","isDnsOnly":false,"hasAutoDns":false,"tags":[]},{"name":"myseconddomain.org","authCode":"xxxxxxxxxx","isTransferLocked":false,"registrationDate":"2009-03-22","renewalDate":"2022-03-22","isWhitelabel":false,"cancellationDate":"","cancellationStatus":"","isDnsOnly":false,"hasAutoDns":false,"tags":[]},{"name":"mythirddomain.org","authCode":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx","isTransferLocked":false,"registrationDate":"2011-09-17","renewalDate":"2022-09-17","isWhitelabel":false,"cancellationDate":"","cancellationStatus":"","isDnsOnly":false,"hasAutoDns":false,"tags":[]}]
```

Comment: Try `$firstDomainName = $firstDomain->getName();`

Comment: That worked a charm. Now I can continue creating a count and loop for update

Comment: Any reason my code did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't like directly accessing protected values, instead you use the "getter" method. Conversely, if you want to set the value of a protected field you use the "setter" method. It was a lucky (but informed) guess on my part that the getter method for the "name" field was `getName()`. You can check the class definition to see which methods are available to you.

Honestly I can't say for sure when exactly you should enforce using getter/setter methods over allowing direct access to elements when defining your own class, but I am certain that using the search terms "getter setter method" will show up some helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the class definition of `Transip\Api\Library\Entity\Domain Object`.  It should have a method to allow you access to the domain name.  The field `name` is protected so it's not accessible to you unless you are extending the class.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the solution to pull the name is there the solution is:

```
<?php

/**
* A script to update all the @ entries in my registrar
*/

require_once (__DIR__ . '/Authenticate.php');

//get all domain information
$domains = $api->domains()->getAll();

//get the current IP address
$ipAddress = file_get_contents('http://ipecho.net/plain');

//set the counter to 0 for first responds
$i = 0;
foreach ($domains as &$value){
   $domain = $domains[$i];
   $domainName = $domain->getName();
   $i = $i + 1;
   echo $domainName;

   // Get the DNS for the current Domain
   $domainDns = $api->DomainDns()->getByDomainName($domainName);
   $domainIp = $domainDns[0];
   $domainIp = $domainIp->getContent();

   //compare the registrar IP to current IP
   if($domainIp == $ipAddress) {
      echo "IP unchanged";
   } else {
      //Here we update the record of the domain that needs changing   
      // Create a DNS entry object
      $dnsEntry = new DnsEntry();
      $dnsEntry->setName('@');
      $dnsEntry->setExpire('300');
      $dnsEntry->setType('A');
      $dnsEntry->setContent($ipAddress);

      // Apply entry
      $api->domainDns()->updateEntry($domainName, $dnsEntry);
   //end of else statement
   }
//end of foreach
}

?>
```

Thank you so much for the help